# What is the Number of Requests/sec (Parse.com)?

Tags: parse-platform

What does the number of requests per second mean ?

A free account has 30 req/sec, What does it technically mean ?, the number of Get/Insert to the database (Data Browser) ? or the number of function calls (Cloud Code) ? or both ?

And is the number of req/s a general number for my account disregarding whether I have 1 or 10 apps ?, or for each app I would get for example 30 req/s ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

It is any of your parse request that start from a client to their server

The previous Parse.com pricing was with a Burst Limit per account. With the new pricing, you should have a Burst Limit per app (customizable paying), it's a bit more convenient. You could change the pricing on parse dashboard in settings, even if you want to keep the free account.

In this [post](https://www.parse.com/questions/burst-limit) a parse member (Shyam) suggest to handle the Burst Limit with:
"Random backoff and retry is probably the best way to handle the burst limit".